# compute data from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, arraylist

I have this (simple) question regarding an array. I am trying to get the total of all the board-feet that was entered in the html. Here's a running sample code: [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/yajeig/8xFFH/190/)

(Thanks to AsKaiser for that code).

Now, what I want to do is that everytime I click the `go` button, it will automatically compute that total board-feet that was being entered in that array. So, everytime I input something in that form and clicked go, the data will go to that array and the total of all board-feet will be displayed in the input box below. It will constantly change as I add data to my array.

I can't get it to work and always have a `NaN` value for my total.

Comment: Works for me, I only get NaN when fields are empty or on invalid data

Comment: yes of course.. But what i want is that evrytime I clicked button go, the total of all the board foot will be display in the input box below. You input some data again and click button go again, and the total below will be updated and all all the board_foot in that array.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/ghostoy/8xFFH/195/

Comment: You're code is great. That is just what I want it to be. Thanks for sharing. By the way, I already voted you up. Dont know who voted you down.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very confusing. What is the point of plank_data?

Why don't you do this instead, it makes more sense.

```
function Plank()
{
  var self = this;
  self.Number = 0;
  self.Thickness = 0;
  self.Width = 0;
  self.Length = 0;
  self.Quantity = 0;

  self.GetBoardFoot = function()
  {
    return (((parseFloat(self.Thickness) * parseFloat(self.Width) * parseFloat(self.Length) * parseFloat(self.Quantity)) / 12);
  }
}

var planks = [];
function AddPlank()
{
  var myPlank = new Plank();
  myPlank.Number = $('#plank_number').val();
  myPlank.Thickness = $('#thickness').val();
  myPlank.Width = $('#width').val();
  myPlank.Length = $('#length_t').val();
  myPlank.Quantity = $('#quantity').val();
  planks.push(myPlank);
}

function GetTotalBoardPlank()
{
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < planks.length; i++)
    total += planks[i].GetBoardFoot();
  return total;
}

function Go()
{
  AddPlank();
  $('#board_foot').val(parseFloat(GetTotalBoardPlank()));
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks to this. But your code really confused me. :) I just stick to mine. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: You should spend some time learning how to use objects, it makes real clear and semantically relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

[Is this what you are looking for?](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/yd3BL/)

```
plank_data = [];
$('#go').click(function() {

    var plankNum = parseFloat($('#plank_number').val() || 0.00),
        thick = parseFloat($('#thickness').val() || 0.00),
        width = parseFloat($('#width').val() || 0.00),
        length_t = parseFloat($('#length_t').val() || 0.00),
        quantity = parseFloat($('#quantity').val() || 0.00);

    //compute board foot
    board_foot = parseFloat((thick * width * length_t * quantity) / 12);

    // show board foot
    $('#board_foot').val(board_foot);

    var current_data = {};

    $('#plank_form input:text:not("#board_foot")').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        current_data[$this.attr('id')] = parseFloat($this.val() || 0.00);
        $this.val('');
    });

    //this will push data/add data to array
    plank_data.push(current_data);

    var total = parseFloat(plankNum + thick + width + length_t + quantity);
    $('#total').val(total);
});
```

Comment: Not really. in my total input box, I want to have the total of all the board foot only that was being entered in the data. You are adding all the data, not the board foot. But thank you for the time.